# Add custom marker to map in flutter with mapbox plugin

Tags: flutter, mapbox, mapbox-gl

to provide a better ui to my app I need to display a small card with the user name and a small circle with the user picture or avatar.

Is there any way to do it with the flutter-mapbox-gl plugin?

Comment: did you find out any solution for adding markers ???

Answer (score 3):

After fighting with this for 2h that's what I came up with:

Add to widget tree:

```
Center(
  child: SizedBox(
    width: double.infinity,
    height: 300,
    child: MapboxMap(
      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
        target: latLng,
        zoom: 13,
      ),
      onMapCreated: onMapCreated,
      accessToken: mapboxPublicToken,
    ),
  ),
)
```

Some remarks:

- `latLng` is e.g. `LatLng(-33.852, 151.211)`
- the `SizedBox` was needed for my case to avoid `Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height` error

Then to add the actual marker (which in my case should be just in the center of the map, same as the `target` of `CameraPosition`):

```
Future<Uint8List> loadMarkerImage() async {
  var byteData = await rootBundle.load("images/poi.png");
  return byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
}

void onMapCreated(MapboxMapController controller) async {
  var markerImage = await loadMarkerImage();

  controller.addImage('marker', markerImage);

  await controller.addSymbol(
    SymbolOptions(
      iconSize: 0.3,
      iconImage: "marker",
      geometry: latLng,
      iconAnchor: "bottom",
    ),
  );
}
```

A few remarks:

- I had no luck with the "built in" markers. [This](https://labs.mapbox.com/maki-icons/) should be the list of supported markers but I couldn't get them to work
- `images/poi.png` in my case is just a 256x256 PNG image with transparent background
- for `rootBundle` to work you need to `import 'package:flutter/services.dart'`
- `iconMarker` tells how to position the marker. In my case it is kind of a pin icon  so I want the "center bottom" to be where the lat/lng is.
- `iconSize` you need to find out the best size. In my case I needed to hot restart every time I did a change which was annoying…

I expanded this answer into a [blog post](http://howto.philippkeller.com/2022/08/01/How-to-create-a-map-in-mapbox-for-flutter/) to cover also some problems I faced during installation.

Answer (score 2):

The best solutions for that is inside mapbox-gl package example folder :
https://github.com/tobrun/flutter-mapbox-gl/blob/master/example/lib/place_symbol.dart

here small example what you can do

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  mapController.addSymbol(
  SymbolOptions(
    geometry: LatLng(-33.86711, 151.1947171),
    iconImage: "assets/images/ur_image.png",
  ),
); 
 return Scaffold(
  body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 300.0,
          child: MapboxMap(
            styleString: themeControl.themeSet.mapStyle,
            onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
            onStyleLoadedCallback: _onStyleLoaded,
            zoomGesturesEnabled: _zoomGesturesEnabled,
            myLocationEnabled: _myLocationEnabled,
            initialCameraPosition: const CameraPosition(
              target: LatLng(-33.852, 151.211),
              zoom: 11.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
);}
```